# Don't quite understand powershells "-Join" and "ConvertTo-Csv"

Tags: powershell, csv, join

I have this code to create a csv and display it as a table:

```
$Keys = ("OrderDate","Region","Rep","Product","Units","Unit Cost","Total")
$Csv = @()    
$Keys | ForEach-Object { 
    $Csv += $_ -Join ","
}
$Csv | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

My output is:

```
OrderDate
OrderDate,Region
OrderDate,Region,Rep
OrderDate,Region,Rep,Product
OrderDate,Region,Rep,Product,Units
OrderDate,Region,Rep,Product,Units,Unit Cost
OrderDate,Region,Rep,Product,Units,Unit Cost,Total

OrderDate
---------
Region   
Rep      
Product  
Units    
Unit Cost
Total
```

I would like these lines to be formatted as headers of a table, like this:

```
OrderDate  Region  Rep  ProductUnits  Unit Cost  Total
-----------  --------  ----  ---------------  -----------  ------
```

Comment: `$Keys | Format-Table`? But question doesn't make much sense without data...

Answer (score 1):

What you're attempting can be done like this:

```
$Keys = "OrderDate","Region","Rep","Product","Units","Unit Cost","Total"
$Object = Select-Object -InputObject 0 -Property $Keys
```

That's typically most useful when you don't know what the properties are when writing the script. The input object doesn't matter as long as it's a scalar value (i.e., not a collection).

To get the exact output you've specified, you'd have to do `$Object | Format-Table` because PowerShell defaults to list output for custom objects, but that changes the object into a string so it's just for display.

A more generally useful pattern to create an object when you do know the properties is to do this:

```
$Object = [PSCustomObject]@{
    "OrderDate" = # Some Value 
    "Region" = # Some Value 
    "Rep" = # Some Value 
    "Product" = # Some Value 
    "Units" = # Some Value 
    "Unit Cost" = # Some Value 
    "Total" = # Some Value 
}
```

Here you instance the object and assign the values you want immediately.